# XDebugging a website with Eclipse/PDT while PHP and the website-files are located on another server ... how?

Tags: php, debian, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

Following situation:

Windows 7 running on my PC.
Also Eclipse with PDT and VMWare, which is my 'server'.

Within the VM I have Debian 5 running, Apache, PHP + XDebug and OpenSSH-Server.

I can connect to Debian with Putty using the IP 192.168.0.128 and Port 3128.

On my Win7-host there is no PHP available.

How can I get Eclipse to connect with XDebug on the VM?

I'm a bit lost here, 'cause I seem to lack some necessary network-basics. Could someone please give me a hint which 'combination of words' will lead me to the solution using Google, usually that's all you need Google + 'the right words' ... tunneling? remote? ... all lead me astray so far.

Thanks

Raffael

Comment: As far as _"the right words"_ goes, I guess remote is the best. The virtual Debian server hosted by VMWare on your PC basically makes both your PC and your Debian server think that they are two separate machines on your local network. Anything* that applies to setting up XDebug between a server and a remote client should apply to your situation (* probably more accurately _almost anything_, as I am sure there will be instances where VMWare needs special care and feeding).

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini on your Debian virtual server, XDebug should have some configuration variables set up. one of them is `xdebug.remote_host`. It is probably set to "localhost" right now. It needs to point back to your Win7 PC's IP address.

In php.ini *(make sure you are editing the one that Apache is using, not the one that PHP CLI is using...they may or may not be the same)*:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.0.999
```

Where *192.168.0.999* is replaced with the PC's IP address.

You need to make sure that `xdebug.remote_port` and `xdebug.remote_handler` are set to the value that your Eclipse plugin is expecting too.

An alternative to specifying an `xdebug.remote_host` would be to use [`xdebug.remote_connect_back`](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back). I've never set that up, so I can't help you more than point you XDebug's docs.

Note that you may need other php.ini settings to set yourself up properly. I'm not an Eclipse user, so I'm not familiar with its special needs (if any).  The XDebug docs or the documentation site for the Eclipse plugin you are using will probably have a basic installation and requirements guide for you.

If you are not sure which php.ini Apache is using, create a php file with `phpinfo();` in it (and nothing else, other than `<?php` to start things out), and then access that file using your browser through the Apache server (drop it in the root directory of the web server). Look for *"Loaded Configuration File"*... should be near the top.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the effort.

For the archive, my configurations:

xdebug.ini:

xdebug.remote_autostart = Off

xdebug.remote_enable = On

xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_host=[HIP]

xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp

xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/apache2/xdebug_remote

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1

[HIP] you get through netstat, in my case it's the (only) SSH conncetion, b/c of putty.

php.ini:

zend_extension=[path you find in xdebug.ii]

Eclipse:

Debugger: XDebug
Server: IP of VM

That did it for me, basically.

Best

Raffael